# How to exclude certain characters from eslint react/no-unescaped-entities eslintrc file?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I'm trying to update my eslintrc file to allow apostrophes without needing to use `&apos;`.

I had a look at the docs in the repo but what's listed there doesn't seem to explain how to allow a character? It only states how to add more characters to the forbidden list.

Can anyone advise me as to where I'm going wrong?

```
"react/no-unescaped-entities": ["error", {"forbid" <I would presume there is an 'allow' option here instead of 'forbid?': ["'"]}],
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'allow' so far, so what you should do is forbid all the escaping except apostrophes:
`"react/no-unescaped-entities": ["error", {"forbid": ['>', '"', '}']}]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: it always seems so obvious when someone gives you the answer :P that's a great help thanks! :D